# Program is asking for input three times the first time, then twice when it shouldn't and ends prematurely

Tags: c++

my code seems to be asking for my numbers three times the first time, then twice when it shouldn't be and is prematurely ending. I can't seem to figure out why.

Little backstory: for August, June, July get 30 days (ignore July 31st) of weather. Use '0' for June, '1' for July, and '2' for August. 'S' for Sunny 'R' for Rainy and 'C' for Cloudy. Store in a 2 dimensional array and display it back to the user in format.

This is what's happening

[image]

and then the bigger picture

[image]

It goes through the list to #30 twice then does exactly what I put at the end

The snippet of code I believe is affecting it

```
// char 'R' = 82
// char 'C' = 67
// char 'S' = 83
bool flag = true;
char temp;
int calendar[3][30];
for( int x = 0; x <= 2; x++)
{
    for( int y = 0; y <= 29; y++)
    {
        if(x==0)
        {
            if(flag)
            {
                cout << "\nPlease enter weather for June";
                flag = false;
            }
            cout << "\nDay #" << y + 1 << " ";
            cin >> temp;
            temp = toupper(temp);
            calendar[x][y] = temp;
            if(y == 29)
                flag = true;
        }
        if(x=1)
        {
            if(flag)
            {
                cout << "\nPlease enter the weather for July, ignoring the 31st";
                flag = false;
            }
            cout << "\nDay #" << y + 1 << " ";
            cin >> temp;
            temp = toupper(temp);
            calendar[x][y] = temp;
            if(y == 29)
                flag = true;
        }
        if(x=2)
        {
            if(flag)
            {
                cout << "\nPlease enter the weather for August";
                flag = false;
            }
            cout << "\nDay #" << y + 1 << " ";
            cin >> temp;
            temp = toupper(temp);
            calendar[x][y] = temp;
            if(y == 29)
                flag = true;
        }

    }
}
flag = false;
for( int n = 0; n <= 2; n++)
{
    for( int m = 0; m <= 29; m++)
    {
        if(n == 0)
        {
            if(flag)
            {
                cout << "\nIn June the days of weather are as follows ";
                flag = false;
            }
            cout << "\n Day #" << m << ": ";
            if(calendar[n][m] == 82)
            {
                cout << "Rainy";
            }
            if(calendar[n][m] == 83)
            {
                cout << "Sunny";
            }
            if(calendar[n][m] == 67)
            {
                cout << "Cloudy";
            }
            if(m == 29)
            {
                flag = true;
            }

        }
        if(n == 1)
        {
            if(flag)
            {
                cout << "\nIn July the days of weather are as follows ";
                flag = false;
            }
            cout << "\n Day #" << m << ": ";
            if(calendar[n][m] == 82)
            {
                cout << "Rainy";
            }
            if(calendar[n][m] == 83)
            {
                cout << "Sunny";
            }
            if(calendar[n][m] == 67)
            {
                cout << "Cloudy";
            }
            if(m == 29)
            {
                flag = true;
            }

        }
        if(n == 2)
        {
            if(flag)
            {
                cout << "\nIn August the days of weather are as follows ";
                flag = false;
            }
            cout << "\n Day #" << m << ": ";
            if(calendar[n][m] == 82)
            {
                cout << "Rainy";
            }
            if(calendar[n][m] == 83)
            {
                cout << "Sunny";
            }
            if(calendar[n][m] == 67)
            {
                cout << "Cloudy";
            }
            if(m == 29)
            {
                flag = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong so any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well without going through all the code in detail, I see two errors right off the bat:

`if(x=1)` and  `if(x=2)`

These should be  `if(x==1)` and  `if(x==2)`